# Why is auto-fill property of CSS Grid not working in column direction

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-grid

I am practicing auto-fill property with rows, however, it is not doing what I desire. I want to create rows with height `minmax(140px, 200px)`, but instead get one row with 200px height and the rest are 18px. Why is it happening?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(140px, 200px));
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"> 1 </div>
  <div class="one"> 1 </div>
  <div class="one"> 1 </div>
  <div class="one"> 1 </div>
  <div class="one"> 1 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To *wrap* grid in vertical direction you have to do a bit more:

- specify a `height` for the *grid container* so that the *grid items* know when to wrap,
- also specify `grid-auto-flow: column` (overriding default `grid-auto-flow: row`)

See demo below (have set `height: 100%` for illustration):

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(140px, 200px));
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* added */
  height: 100%; /* adjust this*/
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"> 1 </div>
  <div class="one"> 2 </div>
  <div class="one"> 3 </div>
  <div class="one"> 4 </div>
  <div class="one"> 5 </div>
</div>
```

---

### Why specify a height?

Because `auto-fill` or `auto-fit` requires a definite dimension in that axis:

> [**`7.2.3.2. Repeat-to-fill: auto-fill and auto-fit repetitions`**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#auto-repeat)
>
> When auto-fill is given as the repetition number, if the grid
>   container has a definite size or max size in the relevant axis, then
>   the number of repetitions is the largest possible positive integer
>   that does not cause the grid to overflow the content box of its grid
>   container (treating each track as its max track sizing function if
>   that is definite or as its minimum track sizing function otherwise,
>   and taking gap into account); if any number of repetitions would
>   overflow, then 1 repetition. Otherwise, if the grid container has a
>   definite min size in the relevant axis, the number of repetitions is
>   the smallest possible positive integer that fulfills that minimum
>   requirement. Otherwise, the specified track list repeats only once.

---

#### Auto-fill in row direction is simpler

Note that here, *you don't need to specify a width* as `display: grid` is a *block element* and block elements have the width of the viewport. You can just use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(140px, 200px))` here:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(140px, 200px));
  /*grid-auto-flow: row; --> default (so not needed) */
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"> 1 </div>
  <div class="one"> 2 </div>
  <div class="one"> 3 </div>
  <div class="one"> 4 </div>
  <div class="one"> 5 </div>
</div>
```

---

### Why `grid-auto-flow: column`?

See the relevant excerpts from its definition - this property controls how *grid items* flow in a *grid container* if they are not explicitly placed:

> [**`grid-auto-flow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow)
>
> The grid-auto-flow CSS property controls how the auto-placement
>   algorithm works, specifying exactly how auto-placed items get flowed
>   into the grid.

The default value of `grid-auto-flow` is `row` which is why you need to *override* it to `column`:

> [**`row`**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#propdef-grid-auto-flow)
>
> The auto-placement algorithm places items by filling each row in turn,
>   adding new rows as necessary. If neither row nor column is provided,
>   row is assumed.