# CSS Grid fit to content and wrap

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm looking for the correct CSS grid syntax to wrap as many child elements in a row and then wrap when no more room.

I have an example set here: 
https://codepen.io/velnias2015/pen/xeeJrZ

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
<span>Spain</span>
<span>France</span>
<span>Germany</span>
<span>Ireland</span>
<span>United Kingdom</span>
<span>Uruguay</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
```

Right now my problem is that the content is not wrapping. Every child element can have a different width based on content. I just want to have as many per row as it can fit, even just 1 and then wrap.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50718701/8620333

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129360/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809466/ (but maybe flexbox is more suited for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556049)

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your container class. Also, because this collapses the margin, add `margin: 2px;` to your `container span` class.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misunderstood. Did you want the codepen example re-made using css grid? If so, go with Temani's link, or check this out too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129360/css-grid-wrapping